# How to use jQuery Datatable in Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, jquery, lwc-dom, datatables.js

I was trying to get jQuery Datatables work in my LWC. 
I have tried this: 
[LWC is it Possible to Load the JQuery Plugin Datatables in a Lightning Web Component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284377/lwc-is-it-possible-to-load-the-jquery-plugin-datatables-in-a-lightning-web-compo)

But I was not able to get it work.
Everything went well until this line of code:
`let dataTable = $(table).DataTable();`
It actually removed the `<table>` element from the page.

Can anybody help me here? 
Thanks in advance!!!

**Code here:**

HTML

```
<template>
    <table lwc:dom="manual" class="example-table display" style="width:100%"></table>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jQuery';
import DATATABLES_JS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/DataTables_js';
import DATATABLES_CSS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/DataTables_css';


renderedCallback() {
    if(firstTimeRender) {
        loadScript(this, jQuery).then(() => {

            console.log('Loaded JQUERY');

            loadStyle(this, DATATABLES_CSS).then(() => {

                console.log('Loaded Datatables CSS');

                loadScript(this, DATATABLES_JS).then(() => {

                    console.log('Loaded Datatables JS');
                    const table = 
                    this.template.querySelector('.example-table');
                    const columnHeaders = ['Id', 'Name'];

                    let columnHeaderHtml = '<thead><tr>';

                    columnHeaders.forEach(function(header) {
                        columnHeaderHtml += '<th>' + header + '</th>';
                    });

                    columnHeaderHtml += '</tr></thead>';

                    table.innerHTML = columnHeaderHtml;

                    let dataTable = $(table).DataTable(); // Here is when it went wrong 

                    this.recordsQueried.forEach(function(r) {
                        dataTable.row.add([
                            r.Id,
                            r.Name
                        ]);
                    }) 
                    dataTable.draw();



            })
        })
    })
}
```

}

Comment: *Can anybody help me here?* Not without seeing your code. Please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have updated the question with my code.

Comment: Have you tried the main bit of the javascript outside of LWC?

Comment: Yes, it works outside LWC...