# Custom DataTable using Vanilla Datables in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to build a custom datable because I want the functionality to sort, search and paginate and also add action buttons in each row. Initially, my VF page was using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) but we have now decided to rebuild that page in LWC.

I found a similar [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284377/lwc-is-it-possible-to-load-the-jquery-plugin-datatables-in-a-lightning-web-compo) but it hasn't really worked for me.

I then found [Vanilla Datatables](https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables) (Javascript) and [Simple Datatables](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables) (ES2018) I have tried to implement Vanilla Datatables but I keep running into issues such as:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The above error is thrown because the library is unable to find the body of the table.

My point is that I feel this library won't work because it's using `document`, `window` and so on.

I was wondering if there is a way I could convert this library to something that is more suited to LWC basically have it "export" the modules. Since I'm not a JS expert I'm unable to put the pieces together.

Just for some context, I'll post my code here:

```
<template>
    <table class="sobject-table slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <template for:each={fieldSetData} for:item="field">
                    <th key={field.apiName} title={field.fieldLabel} class="" data-scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={field.fieldLabel}>{field.fieldLabel}</div>
                    </th>
                </template>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={records} for:item="row">
                <tr key={row} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <template for:each={row} for:item="data">
                        <td key={data.id} data-label="Name" data-scope="row">{data.value}</td>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>


import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import {processRecords} from 'c/recordGenerator';
import getFieldSetData from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSetData.getFieldSetData';
import getSobjectRecords from '@salesforce/apex/DeomoCTRL.getRecords';
import VanillaDatatable from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/VanillaDatatable';
import {loadScript, loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class ManageSelectedIndicators extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    records;
    fieldSetData;
    @wire(
        getFieldSetData,
        {objectName: 'SOBJECTName', fieldSet: 'FIELSETName'}
    ) wiredFieldSetData({error, data}) {
        console.log('wired called in Child')
        if (data) {
            this.fieldSetData = data;
            this.getData();
        }
    }


    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('Constructor called in Child');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Connected callback');
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('Rendered callback');
        Promise.all([
             loadScript(this, VanillaDatatable + '/VanillaDataTables/src/vanilla-dataTables.js')
         ]).then(() => {
             const table = new DataTable(
                 document.getElementsByClassName('.sobject-table'),
                 //Also tried this.template.querySelector('.sobject-table'),
                 {searchable: true, sortable : true}
             );
         })
         .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
         });
    }

    getData() {
        getSobjectRecords ({
            sobjectId: this.recordId
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.records= processRecords(response, this.fieldSetData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

}
```

**Edit:** I have also tried `lwc:dom="manual"` that didn't seem to work either.

Is there any other way I could achieve these functionalities? Or do I have to write custom code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library "may" work if you use `lwc:dom="manual"` and construct the table that way, but it has to be done entirely in JavaScript without a template. I'm not sure that's something you want to do.

That said, lightning:datatable already has sorting capabilities built-in, and you could build pagination around it if you wanted to. There's no need to get an external library involved.

If you want an example in Aura, I wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/66488eb80292c7151f616ebe7d1b0a18). It's "old", but demonstrates everything you want to do in Aura.

If you insist on LWC, you can do that, too, demonstrated by this [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8FsYVEEg/1/edit).

I'll include the code, below.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track pageRecords;
    @track allRecords;
    @track thisPage = 0;
    @track pageSize = 10;
    @track sortedBy = 'value1';
    @track sortedDirection = 'asc';
    @track columns = [
        { fieldName: 'value1', label: 'Value 1', sortable: true, type: 'number' },
        { fieldName: 'value2', label: 'Value 2', sortable: true, type: 'number' }
    ];
    connectedCallback() {
        let data = [];
        while(data.length < 1000) {
            data.push({
                id: data.length+'',
                value1: Math.random()*1000,
                value2: Math.random()*1000
            });
        }
        this.allRecords = data;
        this.maxPage = Math.floor((this.allRecords.length+this.pageSize-1)/this.pageSize);
        this.sort();
    }
    sort(event) {
        if(event) {
            this.sortedDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
            this.sortedBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        }
        let direction = this.sortedDirection === 'asc'? 1: -1;
        this.allRecords = this.allRecords.sort(
            (a,b) => (a[this.sortedBy]-b[this.sortedBy])*direction
        );
        this.loadPage();
    }
    loadPage() {
        this.pageRecords = this.allRecords.filter(
            (v,i) => Math.floor(i/this.pageSize)===this.thisPage
        );
    }
    prevPage() {
        if(this.thisPage) {
            this.thisPage = this.thisPage - 1;
            this.loadPage();
        }
    }
    nextPage() {
        if(this.thisPage < this.maxPage) {
            this.thisPage = this.thisPage + 1;
            this.loadPage();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable 
        columns={columns}
        data={pageRecords}
        sorted-by={sortedBy}
        sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
        key-field="id"
        onsort={sort}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    <lightning-button label="Prev" onclick={prevPage}>
    </lightning-button>
    {thisPage}/{maxPage}
    <lightning-button label="Next" onclick={nextPage}>
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Comment: I have tried the `lwc:dom="manual"` and that didn't seem to work as well. I'll edit my question to reflect that. I can't use the lightning:datatable because, I would have to add other functionalities in the future which might not be scalable. But I think you are right, I might end up not using a library.

Comment: @d_k Maybe, maybe not? The LWC lightning-datatable actually lets you extend it with custom data types.

Comment: yeah but what about a hidden column and search that would have to be custom too yeah I think?

Comment: @d_k You don't need a hidden column, as the data is driven from the table. Searching is also pretty trivial.