# Jquery UI failing for My lwc app

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, jquery

I am trying to use the jQuery sortable functionality for my LWC app where I can reorder items in a column and even move them from column to column. I have the jquery and jquery UI libraries loaded in my app but it is still not working. All I keep getting is an error
**aura_prod.js:956 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined**
I have attached the code below:

.HTML

```html
<template>
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
      </ul>
       
</template>
```

.css

```css
.sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 60%; 
}

.sortable li { 
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 0.4em; 
    padding-left: 1.5em; 
    font-size: 1.4em; 
    height: 18px; 
}

.sortable li span { 
    position: absolute; 
    margin-left: -1.3em;
}
```

.js

```js
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jQuery';
import jQueryUI from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jQueryUI';


export default class Dragger_Component extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getAccounts) accounts;
    renderedCallback(){
        loadScript(this, jQuery)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('JQuery loaded.');
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('Failed to load the JQuery : ' +error);
        });

         loadScript(this, jQueryUI)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('JQueryUI loaded.');
            $(this.template.querySelector('.sortable')).sortable();        
            $(this.template.querySelector('.sortable')).disableSelection();
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log('Failed to load the JQueryUI : ' +error);
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: I doubt that jQuery UI is compatible with LWC given that it manipulates the DOM, but can you provide at what point the error is occurring? Does the renderedCallback complete? Does the error happen when you attempt to click and drag an item?

Comment: Any attempt to click and drag results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow manual DOM manipulation:

```
<ul class="sortable" lwc:dom="manual">
```

See [Using Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library).

See also [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/284389/2984) for a complete example of jQuery and DataTable. Note that not all jQuery plugins and versions of jQuery will be compatible with LWC. You may need to try a different version if errors persist.